# Getting 404 error only when using .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create a `version` in JIRA for a specific project.

I'm able to do the process via Postman by building my requests manually, but it fails with a 404 when creating the version record via .NET.

I'm assuming .NET adds pesky parameters to the request that Postman doesn't do.

The weird thing is that the authentication call works, but the the version creation fails.

Here's the helper I wrote:

```
public class JIRA
{
   private string AuthToken { get; set; }

   private const string c_JIRAUrl = "https://org.atlassian.net";

   private const string c_LoginUrl = c_JIRAUrl + "/rest/auth/1/session";
   private const string c_CreateVersionUrl = c_JIRAUrl + "/rest/api/2/version";


    public JIRA()
    {

        //this works...
        var authResponse = ExecuteRequest(c_LoginUrl, "POST", new
        {
            username = "login",
            password = "password"
        });

        AuthToken = authResponse["session"]["value"].ToString();

    }

    public void CreateVersion(string name, string projectKey, ProjectEnvironment environment)
    {
        //lets hardcode the same data I use in Postman for testing purposes...
        var createVersionResponse = ExecuteRequest(c_CreateVersionUrl, "POST", new
        {
            description = "An excellent version",
            name = "1.1.2",
            archived = false,
            released = false,
            project = "TEST"
        });

    }

    private JObject ExecuteRequest(string url, string method, object data)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response;
        var jsonDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonDataString);
        var responseText = string.Empty;

        var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        wr.ContentType = "application/json";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AuthToken))
            wr.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, $"Bearer {AuthToken}");
        wr.Method = method;
        wr.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        wr.Accept = "application/json";

        using (var webStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
        {
            webStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        }

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return JObject.Parse(responseText);
    }


}
```

The `CreateVersion` method always fails with a 404.

As I've said, doing the same (retrieving the token, creating the version) all works in Postman.

Any ideas what's going on ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when retrieving the token (`/rest/auth/1/session`) the response contains cookies that POSTMAN was sending back in the 2nd request (creating the version). I had to fire up Fiddler to find out it was doing so because its UI was not saying so.

My .NET client was not doing so. When making it do so, it works.

I'm a little miffed that a REST service expects cookies...